# Add sorting to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, html-table

I need some help in table sorting in PHP. This command:

```
print_r($pieces);
```

prints me this:

```
Array (
[0] => John
[1] => 22
[2] => blue
[3] => offline
)

Array (
[0] => Ann
[1] => 19
[2] => 897505034
[3] => red
[4] => online
)

Array (
[0] => Mike
[1] => 31
[2] => 897505034
[3] => yellow
[4] => online
)
```

And then I fill the table with this records.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pieces[0] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pieces[1] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pieces[2] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pieces[3] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $pieces[4] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

John,22,blue,offline
Ann,19,897505034,red,online
Mike,31,897505034,yellow,online
```

I don't know how to change the order of filling the table by sorting the items by age for example:

```
Ann,19,897505034,red,online
John,22,blue,offline
Mike,31,897505034,yellow,online
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [**`Usort`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Do like this

```
 <?php
$pieces=array(array (
    0 => 'John',
    1 => 22,
    2 => 'blue',
    3 => 'offline'
),

    array (
        0 => 'Ann',
        1 => 19,
        2 => 897505034,
        3 => 'red',
        4 => 'online'
    ),

    array (
        0 => 'Mike',
        1 => 31,
        2 => 897505034,
        3 => 'yellow',
        4 => 'online'
    ));

usort($pieces,function($a,$b){ return $a[1]<$b[1]?-1:$a[1]!=$b[1];});


foreach($pieces as $arr){
foreach($arr as $v){
    echo  $v." ";
}
echo "\n";

}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/134587)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**

```
Ann 19 897505034 red online 
John 22 blue offline 
Mike 31 897505034 yellow online
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be what I want, but I'll check it tomorrow in my code. Could you explain me this part after _return_, especially _-1_?

Answer (score 0):

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

```
$pieces = array_multisort(array_column($pieces, 1), SORT_ASC, $pieces);
```